# Tunneling through a proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

My Intranet users are accessing the Internet through a proxy on the network. I need to monitor and filter certain requests to that proxy on a few machines. In essence, I need to *proxy the proxy* on the local machine.

How do I insert a local application as a relay between the local system and the Intranet proxy?

I would have to change the local proxy settings to an endpoint on the local machine, which in turn should relay HTTP requests to the outside proxy. But, I have no experience with writing proxies. Is this even possible?

---

**Edit:** The term I was looking for is *tunneling*, not proxying through a proxy. It is possible and I managed it with a TCP pipe.

Comment: They'll figure out how to bypass yours in less than a week.  Your existing proxy ought to already have this capability.

Comment: @Hans, not a concern. This is not a security application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a custom TCP tunnel that forwards requests to the Intranet proxy and pointed the browser proxy to the local machine.

Answer (score 2):

**Why not use an existing proxy server?** This has all required capabilities and you don't have to worry about stability and performance.